# Juxtaposed transducers

Tags: clojure

Let's imagine we want to compute two different functions on some given input. How can we do that with transducers?

For example, let's say we have these two transducers:

```clj
(def xf-dupl (map #(* 2 %)))
(def xf-inc (map inc))
```

Now, I would like some function `f` that takes a collection of transducers and returns a new transducer that combines them, as follows:

```clj
(into [] (f [xf-dupl xf-inc]) (range 5))
; => [[0 2 4 6 8] [1 2 3 4 5]]
```

There should probably be a very simple solution to this, but I cannot find it.

Note: I have tried with cgrand/xforms library's transjuxt, but there I get the following

```clj
(into [] (x/transjuxt {:a xf-dupl :b xf-inc}) (range 5))
; => [{:a 0 :b 1}]
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using cgrand/xforms you can define `f` as

```clj
(defn f
  [xfs]
  (comp
    (x/multiplex (zipmap (range) xfs))
    (x/by-key (x/into []))
    (map second)))
```

Calling `f` as you outlined in your question yields

```
user> (into [] (f [xf-dupl xf-inc]) (range 5))
[[0 2 4 6 8] [1 2 3 4 5]]
```